# eps attachment parsing with javamail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, eps

Is any special handling required to parse the eps attachment in the eml using javamail
I dont have any issue other types of attachments. only eps attachment gives problem

When i send the eps attachment using outlook 2010 it converts encoding from base64 to quoted-printable.

Below is the header of the eps attachment i am trying to parse.

Content-Type: application/postscript;
name="LOGO.eps"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: attachment;
filename="LOGO.eps"

The attachment is extracted. But when i open it with document viewer it says loading forever

Answer (score 0):

JavaMail tries to guess the best Content-Transfer-Encoding for the data by looking at the actual data.  If JavaMail guesses that the data is text, it's likely to use quoted-printable.  In some cases, the guess can be wrong, in which case you'll need to specify the encoding yourself.  If you're using JavaMail 1.5, there's a [new attachFile method](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#attachFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) that makes this easier.

Comment: thanks. i don't have issue in generating the attachment stream. but only in parsing it. The quoted-printable encoding is set by outlook2010. i am parsing the attachment using javamail

Comment: Then you'll need to say more about how you're "parsing" it, and what this "document viewer" is that you're opening it with.  Are you saving it to a file before you open/parse it?

Comment: Multipart mp= Part.getContent; MimeBodyPart mbp=Multipart.getContent(); then get the stream from mimebodypart.getInputStream() and write into a file. Read using linux document viewer

Comment: You're probably not saving it to the file correctly.  See [this JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#readattach).